# Ruby - Reading csv file and executing value in loop is skipping over lines in the csv file

Tags: ruby, csv, for-loop

I'm sure this is a completely ignorant question but here it goes.  The following code's objective is to read a list of id's from a standard csv file, use the value to append to a URL, call the URL and extract a specific attribute via xpath.  The problem I'm having is that the loop seems to be skipping some lines.

In example, here is a sample of 10 values:

```
777961
777972
781033
781044
781055
847066
744187
893908
369009
369010
```

The code is only reading every other line.  The actual file has around 6000 lines, not huge but I'm only getting about 2500 values returned in the second file.

```
f = File.open('test.csv', 'r+')

url_f = File.open("url.csv", "w")

for line in f
  f.each_line do |item|
    item = f.gets
    url = "http://test.com/testid=" + item
    client = HTTPClient.new
    resp = client.get_content(url)

    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(resp)
      doc.xpath("//link[@rel='canonical']/@href").each do |attr|
      url_f.puts attr.value
      puts attr.value
      end
    puts item
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I figured it out.

I had the line `item = f.gets` which would call the next line every time the loop ran thus skipping every other line.  I knew it was a noob question.  :P